# how to return fragment of compatible type

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using viewpager with fragments. i defined three fragments, each in a separate class file "Frag_1, Frag_2, Frag_3" that extends Fragment 
 class. but when i instantiate and object from any of the fragment class as shown below in the switch-case i receive incompatible type error and 
 it says:

```
 it required xx.xx.xx.app.fragment
 and found is vpager_00.Frag_1
```

how to solve it

**code**:

```
public class VPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int mNumOfTabs;

public VPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Frag_1 tab1 = new Frag_1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Frag_2 tab2 = new Frag_2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Frag_3 tab3 = new Frag_3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

**imports in VPagerAdapter class**:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import com.example.com.vpager_00.Frag_1;
import com.example.com.vpager_00.Frag_2;
import com.example.com.vpager_00.Frag_3;
```

Comment: please show the code of one of your Fragment classes

Comment: java's basics ... `Frag_X` should extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (prolly you are extending `android.app.Fragment`)